# Let $m^n-1$ be prime. What can $m$ be?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $m^n-1$ be prime. What can $m$ be if $m$ and $n$ are not $1$?

How can I find $m$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html

Answer (score 17):

Hint: $m^n-1 = (m-1)(m^{n-1}+m^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$.

Comment: Still don't get it...

Comment: m = 2 and m-1=1 ..

Comment: @user75283 If $m>2$ then the RHS is a composite number.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but what is RHS ?

Comment: "Right hand side" (of the equation).

Answer (score 2):

If $m = 1$, the expression gives 0, not a prime. Ruled out.

If $m \ge 2$, we have the factorization $m^n - 1 = (m - 1) (m^{n - 1} + m^{n - 2} + \ldots + 1)$. This can only be a prime if $n = 1$ (in which case the second factor is 1) or if $m = 2$ (when the first factor is 1).

So, either $n = 1$ and $m - 1$ is a prime or $m = 2$ and $n \ge 2$ (not all $n$ work, mind you).

Comment: 2^4 - 1 = 15 and 7^2-1=13

Comment: So m could be 7?

Comment: @user75283, $7^2 - 1 = (7 - 1) \cdot (7 + 1) = 48$. And no, $m$ is a prime + 1, i.e., $m = 1010$ works fine.

Comment: 3+1=4, 4^2=16 , 16-1=15, 15 isn't prime

Comment: It is one _or_ the other pair of cases. You can have $n = 1$, in which case $m = p + 1$ for $p$ prime works. Or for $n > 1$  it has to be $m = 2$.